# How to enable back "View prоblem details" on crash for WERFault?

Tags: windows-7, windows-error-reporting

I just reinstalled Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, and when an app crashes, its WERFault window is now different from my previous installation's, without an option to show crash details. Previous OS installation was made in early 2013. My notebook wad upgraded to the same OS about half a year later form that, and the same thing happened to it. I think this might be caused by a recent windows update.

This is how WERFault window looked before:

[image]

And this is how it looks now:

[image]

How do I see crash details again?

Note that in both OS installations, I had Visual Studio 2010 installed, so these screenshots I found on google may not be the same in all cases (missing debug option).

Comment: Do you get a **Debug** button like the second screenshot? Start `regedit.exe`, and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting`. Post a screenshot of the values shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Check you windows Error reporting settings:

Error reporting can be controlled through

`Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Problem Reporting Settings`.

An administrator, or a user with administrative credentials, can modify the settings to:
Enable or disable Windows Error Reporting, for all users or a specific user.

Set the consent level (described earlier) for Windows Error Reporting, for all users or a specific user.

*CHECK* the programs for which error reports should never be sent.
[image]

Comment: It's `Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Problem Reporting Settings` in my Win7 x64 ultimate, which version is your path for?

Comment: @user1306322 That path is for Windows Vista. [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709644%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)